# how to display Image in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am trying to get the image(which is in binary array or BLOB) to show up in crystal report, am using Stored procedure to get all column value to display into crystal report, and all data are displaying fine except the image, I tried searching for answers including Stackoverflow but no gain,

**INFORMATION**

> Image is already stored in database, and column type is "Image" type
>
> when right click on the image filed and this is the path I get "localhost:51194/CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_31f82389-f333-44eb-8d37-ca3616f40ecc.png"

am attaching images too, if at all I am doing wrong please let me know, and guide me how to display that images, any help will be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the data type you selected for the image in Crystal reports

Comment: In sql it is "Image" type, I don't know what you talking about datatype in crystal report ?? please give me some more information, as showed above image, when selected "Format Object" it shows "Blob Field"